# dispatch_after wont run code under it when executed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

When I use the dispatch_after method to produce a delay it never executes the code after it. I need to return an array but it always skips over it.

Here is [matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) delay method:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Here is the method where the error occurs:

```
func rollDice() -> Array<Int> {
    var diceArray = [Int]()
    let timerTime:NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    delay(timerTime) {
        //my code
    }
    return diceArray //NEVER GETS HERE
}
```

Comment: Actually, that's _my_ `delay` method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861

Comment: @matt sorry for not crediting you. I edited it so it now links to your page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to understand what a delay is. The code will operate in this order:

```
func rollDice() -> Array<Int> {
    var diceArray = [Int]() // ONE
    let timerTime:NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    delay(timerTime) {
        // THREE
    }
    return diceArray // TWO
}
```

So, your `rollDice` will return an empty `diceArray` before the code inside the `delay` ever runs. Whatever you are doing inside the `delay` is thus ineffective from that point of view; it has, and can have, no effect whatever on what `rollDice` returns.

Comment: He could refactor his `rollDice()` method to take a completion handler (where he passes back the array).

Comment: @NicolasMiari Absolutely. He could do a lot of things. But the question wasn't what to do (to gain some end - but what end? I'm not entirely sure what he's even _trying_ to do). The question was to explain the phenomenon of what's happening.